# RPC windows get client IP address

Tags: c, windows, rpc

I have read [loads of Microsoft documentation regarding RPC programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378651.aspx) and still do not figure out how do we get from RPC server the IP address of the connecting client.

I am sure there is a simple way to get client IP address from server when connecting, but do not know how to do this :/

Thanks for helping, a simple pointer to a documentation would be great.

Comment: MSDN states it's possible using RpcBindingServerFromClient() function. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - there is no documented way to accomplish this.  Windows RPC by design abstracts the network transport (and associated metadata like network addresses) from it's clients.

If you really need something like this, you could bake it into your interface (e.g. implement a Connect() method where your client provides it's IP address that you could stash in a [Context Handle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373605%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).  This assumes of course, that you can trust your clients to provide valid IP addresses...

Comment: Note that you *can* get information about the user account used to authenticate.  That's usually of more interest to an RPC server than the client IP address.

Comment: Thanks for your answers; I am quite a newbie on RPC programming; @HarryJohnston, do you have a pointer to any documentation page providing more information on this point? I have the feeling having crawled the whole web without finding any working example; Microsoft documentation seems rather outdated. Many thanks!

Comment: I believe you start with RpcImpersonateClient, then OpenThreadToken, then GetTokenInformation.

Comment: MSDN states it's possible using RpcBindingServerFromClient() function. See my answer.

Comment: Incredible how there is no a simple built-in solution to identify an RPC client  from server side. Mind-blowing and frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

It should be possible using RpcBindingServerFromClient. Quoting documentation for [RpcBindingServerFromClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375604(v=vs.85).aspx):

> To query a client's address, an application starts by calling the RpcBindingServerFromClient function to obtain a partially bound server binding handle. The server binding handle can be used to obtain a string binding by invoking RpcBindingToStringBinding. The server can then call RpcStringBindingParse to extract the client's network address from the string binding.

**UPDATE 16/05/2017:** There is also undocumented function I_RpcServerInqRemoteConnAddress() that most likely return client IP address. But I didn't try it yet.